# excel vba add a set number of items to a collection

Tags: vba, excel, collections

I have the following set of code:

```
For loopCounter = 2 To endRow
Dim item As Variant
Dim lineArray()
Dim myString As String

myString = Cells(loopCounter, 3).Value

ReDim lineArray(1 To endColumn)

If Not (Left(myString, 1) = "P" Or Left(myString, 1) = "I" Or myString = "RESW" Or myString = "REPC") Then
     For x = 1 To endColumn
          lineArray(x) = dataArray(loopCounter, x)
     Next x

     itemCollection.Add lineArray
End If
Next loopCounter
```

For the purpose of keeping this question short and to the point, I have a bunch of excel worksheets that contains hundreds of rows of data. To make a long story short, the code above add items from the worksheet to the collection, but it's adding every row (minus the conditions I set - if statement). However, I only want to add a fix amount of items to the collection, 15. I can't seem to figure it out and haven't found any help online.

My question for help is, does anyone know how I can make it that once 15 items are added to the collection it will exit out of the loop and finish the rest of the subroutine?

I purposely didn't add the whole code because it's quite lengthy and not necessary.

Thank you.

Comment: change `For loopCounter = 2 To endRow` to `For loopCounter = 2 To 16`

Comment: Or just keep a count of how many items you add to the collection, then exit the loop when it's 15.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure thing, just check on the collection.Count > 14 then exit for

```
For loopCounter = 2 To endRow
Dim item As Variant
Dim lineArray()
Dim myString As String

myString = Cells(loopCounter, 3).Value

ReDim lineArray(1 To endColumn)

If Not (Left(myString, 1) = "P" Or Left(myString, 1) = "I" Or myString = "RESW" Or myString = "REPC") Then
     For x = 1 To endColumn
          lineArray(x) = dataArray(loopCounter, x)
     Next x

     itemCollection.Add lineArray
     if itemCollection.Count = 15 then exit for
End If
Next loopCounter
```

if it would have been an array, then use if UBOUND(array) = 14 then exit for

Comment: It worked perfectly and I can't believe it was just a one liner. Thanks!

Comment: it's a pleasure Tim! (p.s. don't forget the upvote :))